# Is it possible to avoid finding my operator via the search menu?

Tags: python, operator

I was wondering if it was possible to avoid making `bpy.ops.myscript.doesomething()`available in the search menu of blender?

I think it is not possible, but I would like to have some information about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the manual : https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operators#bpy.types.Operator.bl_options

setting

```py
bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}
```

should remove the operator from search results.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, It completely eliminates my operators from the search, very useful if they are built to be hidden from the interface in certain situations, thanks for the help